# Changing an attribute in ActiveRecord Relation object during call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named `Partner` that has the attributes of `name:string` and `trial: boolean` and I am calling this model in the following manner:

```
 options_from_collection_for_select(Partner.all, :id, :name, current_user.partner_id),
```

Rather than it showing the `:name`, how can I include another condition so that it adds "(Trial)"?

So essentially I'd like for it to check if whether or not `trial` is true, and then append that for its name so that the partner doesn't look like `PartnerA` but `PartnerA (Trial)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a method on your model

```
class Partner < ApplicationRecord
   def name_for_collection
     if trial
       "#{name} (Trial)"
     else 
       name
     end
   end
 end
```

You will probably want to shorten this method in a real project to something like this though...

```
 def name_for_collection
   return name unless trial
   "#{name} (Trial)"
 end
```

and in your view you use this method...

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Partner.all, :id, :name_for_collection, current_user.partner_id),
```

Read more about [options_from_collection_for_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes perfect sense!

Answer (score -1):

After doing some source sleuthing (see [form_options_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L399)), I believe you can do this in the view layer (and not muddle up your model), by passing a `Proc/Lamba` in as an argument for the `text_method` parameter:

```rb
# Here's the method signature
def options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)

# And you should be able to use it like this
options_from_collection_for_select(Partner.all, :id, -> (partner) { "#{partner.name} #{'(Trial)' if partner.trial?}".strip }, current_user.partner_id)
```

For a bit more context: `options_from_collection_for_select` calls the method `value_for_collection`, which in turn checks to see if `value_method` or `text_method` is proc-like and invokes it if so.

You might want to use this approach if your values will only be shown like this in one or two locations in the app to keep presentational logic out of your model.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Manipulating values from the database in your view when they are for presentation-only is a perfectly reasonable and good thing to do.  Keeping that logic out of the model can be a good thing.  If you find that modifying the model makes sense for your use case, you can do that, but this is also a valid approach.